# How to display code line number (without additional context) in Icecream print outputs?

Tags: python, debugging, icecream

I am currently using Icecream (https://github.com/gruns/icecream) to print variables and other info for debugging and review purposes. I would like to be able to display the line number where the print call originated from, without including additional information. I don't need to be using Icecream if there is a better option.

The code below can produce the following output.

```
1 - from icecream import ic
2 - test = 'hello'
3 - ic(test)
```

> `ic| test: 'hello'`

This is great, and I can adjust the prefix how I like, but I want to also be able to include the line number that generated the output. Icecream has a function that can do this, but it also outputs a bunch of other information that I am not interested in (see below).

```
1 - from icecream import ic
2 - ic.configureOutput(prefix=f'Debug | ', includeContext=True)
3 - test = 'hello'
4 - ic(test)
```

> `Debug | test.py:4 in <module>- test: 'hello'`

There doesn't seem to be a native way to just show the line number (4 in the above example) without the rest of the information (filename and parent function). What I can do is include some code in the prefix editor to get a line number, but this just gives me with the line number of the ic.configureOutput() function, which I suppose makes sense, because this is the function that made the line number request.

```
1 - from icecream import ic
2 - import sys
3 - def line_number():
4 -     return sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno
5 - ic.configureOutput(prefix=f'Debug:{line_number()} | ')
6 - test = 'hello'
7 - ic(test)
```

> `Debug:5 | test: 'hello'`

Is there a way (or some other method entirely) to get the above output, but have the line number (line 5 in the above example) be the actual line number in the script that originated the call (this would be 7 in the above example)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use "inspect" library for this purpose;

```
from inspect import currentframe

def get_line();
    return currentframe().f_back_f_lineno

print("this is sample:", get_line())
```

Comment: Agreed, this will get the line number when I call the "get_line" function. Unfortunately, to integrate it with Icecream I call that function only once as I insert it into the Icecream prefix, then any time I use Icecream after that it simply uses the same line number where the Icecream prefix was updated.
/n
This is similar to the example I provided at the end, but I used sys._getframe() instead of currentframe(), but it is the same result. I want to be able to see the line number where the Icecream function is called, not the line number where the Icecream prefix was updated. Possible?